# Sorting a couchdb database by muliple fields in Java Ektorp Library

Tags: java, sorting, couchdb, ektorp

I am trying to make a website which lists data in a table from a CouchDB database. I tried adding a view as seen below:

```
    @View( name = "all", map = "function(doc) { if (doc.type == 'sofa' ) emit( [doc.sofaID,doc.timesofa], doc._id )}")
    public List<TVreport> getAllTVreports() {
        List<TVreport> couchresults = null;
        try {
            ViewQuery q = new ViewQuery().allDocs().includeDocs(true);
            couchresults = sofadb.queryView(q, TVreport.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return couchresults;
}
```

This results in no change to the order of the list. I need to be able to sort by both sofaID and timesofa which I made as unique keys. I am using Ektorp Java library.

Comment: You're trying to **sort** or to filter?

Comment: {
         "_id": "0d4f367125e7c2b882d6df6fde00a8a6",
         "_rev": "1-ee6e1bc6178678112b7446502f8e9dcc",
         "tvname": "sofa01.lazy.com",
   "sofavalue": "65.4683"
   "sofaID": "1080",
   "sofaname": "sofa00.lazy.com",
   "tvsignallevel": "22",
   "timesofa": "2016-08-02 11:19:52.520375"
}
I'm trying to sort by any of the two fields. @AlexisCôté